# Javascript: Is there any way to use the window as a cartesian plane?

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to print something like this
        [image: Way I want it to print]

What am I asking if there is a way to go back once one prints? I mean using the window as an x-y coordinate.

Comment: You need to provide a lot more detail and an example of what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

try to use the [`canvas`](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp) object.

You can also use `CSS` `top` `left` attributes (use `px` pixels as unity) to place your elements like on a **X/Y plane**. better if you set the `position` attribute to `absolute` also the cartesian plane inherits from you parent element.

Answer (score 0):

As JSmith told you, you can use a canvas element, but if you want to repaint the positions after some time, maybe the best will be to add an "id" to every element for future changes on this coordinates. Sorry, this is all I can help you without more information